access array items with key & index
I try to create a "keyed" array, where items can be accessed by the index (like a regular array) and a .key property defined in the item object.
The problem(s):

I have concern about the consistency
Array methods can be overridden
Implement all methods (.slice, .splice. etc.)



class Commands extends Array {
  constructor(items) {
    super(...items);

    items.forEach(item => {
      this[item.key] = item;
    });
  }

  push(...items) {
    super.push(...items);

    items.forEach(item => {
      this[item.key] = item;
    });
  }
}

const commands = new Commands([
  {
    key: "a",
    name: "A",
  },
  {
    key: "b",
    name: "B",
  },
  {
    key: "c",
    name: "C",
  },
]);

console.log("commands", commands);

console.log("item a", commands.a);
console.log("item c", commands[2]);

commands.a.name = "foo";
//commands.slice(0, 1); // throws error "TypeError: Spread syntax requires ...iterable[Symbol.iterator] to be a function"

console.log(commands);



So my question is: Is this a good approach (in terms of "for most use cases"), or should handle it in a other way, e.g. wrap the array in a proxy and handle the "get by key" stuff in get trap, or something complete else?
EDIT:
Answer to @pilchard question in the comments: I want to have a "shortcut", something that is user defined, to access the item. In a large array to work with indexes is not as easy as to say you want item commands.c compared to:
const index = commands.indexOf((item) => {
  return item.key === "c";
});

const element = commands[index];


You haven't indicated why you need such a structure, but on first glance this is probably not a good pattern 'for most use cases', it interrupts expected Array behavior and doesn't address any of the Object specific limitations (duplicate keys etc.)

Whether it's a "good approach for most use cases" feels entirely opinion-based. I think it's better to just create a lookup object from your array at the times you need it, rather than bogging down the performance of all your array operations. Not to mention all the edge cases you'd need to address like sparse arrays, key values clashing with index values, etc. to get to an implementation that is correct and consistent.

discussion here: Lookup of values: create Javascript Object out of Array first or do use find()? and JavaScript fast lookup data structure? or look at binary search Binary Search in Javascript

i have an exact solution you need (more over it's in a prod), let's hope the question will be re-opened

If you've an array of objects with unique key properties, you could add the same keys to the array as non-enumerable properties. That way you could refer to the object directly by array.key. This will create a ton of problems, though, like need of manual update of the keys etc.

@AlexanderNenashev I created a chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257750/78516005 Feel free to join, and lets discuses there.

You can use Proxy, to provide access with both the keys and indices. You can also cache the found items by key, reset the cache on any methods that mutate array


class Commands extends Array {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        return new Proxy(this, {
            get: (...args) => {
                const prop = args[1];
                if (prop in this) {
                    return Reflect.get(...args);
                }
                return this.find(item => item.key === prop);
            },

        });
    }
}

const commands = new Commands(...[
    {
        key: "a",
        name: "A",
    },
    {
        key: "b",
        name: "B",
    },
    {
        key: "c",
        name: "C",
    },
]);

console.log("commands", commands);
console.log("item a", commands.a);
console.log("item c", commands[2]);

commands.a.name = "foo";

console.log(commands.slice(0, 1));
.as-console-wrapper{ max-height: 100% !important}




Interesting approach with returning the proxy in the constructor. Im a bit surprised that returning a proxy in the constructor does not break the class methods. e.g. for clearing the cache or mess up the prototype chain

@Marc accessing prototype chain methods through proxy is ok for Array but if want to use objects related to DOM (window, Event) or for example RegExp we need an extra efforts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78457068/javascript-proxy-not-working-for-opened-window-object/78457126#78457126

You can use a Proxy to retrieve values from an Array two ways. Here's an example:


const commands = CommandsFactory([
  { key: "a", name: "A", },
  { key: "b", name: "B", },
  { key: "c", name: "C", },
]);

console.log(`commands[2]: ${commands[2]}`);
console.log(`commands.c: ${commands.c}`);
console.log(`commands[5]: ${commands[5]}`);
console.log(`commands.iDontExist: ${commands.iDontExist}`);


function CommandsFactory(arr) {
  // the proxy get handler returns the
  // *name* property from either a numeric 
  // value (index) or from a given key.
  // Returns undefined for non existing
  // indexes or keys
  const prxy = {
    get: (target, key) => {
      return key in target && target[key]?.name || 
        target.find(v => v.key === key)?.name;
    } 
  }

  return new Proxy(arr, prxy);
}



